# Qt - Prevent window resize when dragging title bar

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface, qt5

I want my window to be **always** maximized. I try setting:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
(...)
showMaximized();
setMinimumSize(QSize(width(), height()));
setFixedSize(QSize(width(), height()));
```

So the window is opened maximized, but I can still click its title bar and drag it down. When doing so Windows (10) is resizing window from maximized state to normal.

How can I disable this behavior for my window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the concept of *maximizing* the window is less efficient to maintain a dragable window. Instead , set the window geometry to maximum screen dimensions, then you can drag as needed without the system resizing your window.
To do that you need an instance of `QDesktopWidget` which provides geometry information of your screen, like the full stretch width/height. then just set your window size to be fixed with those information. 
In your Mainwindow .cpp add following:

```
QDesktopWidget* myscreen = QApplication::desktop();
int width = myscreen->width();
int height = myscreen->height();
this->setFixedSize(width, height);
ui->setupUi(this);
```

...
...

**Edit**
The window can still be fully dogging, you can still use `w.showMaximized();` and the window won't drop its size upon drag.

Comment: Mhh, well almost. If I use your code, my window won't be docked as it should in the maximized state. 
But if I use `setMinimumSize()` instead of `setFixedSize()` then it's working (almost) as I wanted. Ideally I would like to disable possibility to drag the window (so it's always maximized) but keeping its size the same is good-enough solution.

Comment: Yes I know it won't dock 100% ..  a small margin is left at the sides.

Comment: And by the way you can still show your window maximized, it wont resize upon drag

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows is always going to respond to the user clicking and dragging the title bar, you could consider `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`.  Then draw your own faux title bar as rectangle on the top of the window with your own minimized and close buttons as needed.  You'll also need to draw your own border rectangle.

Comment: Thanks, but that's more like a workaround than solution. Maybe it's not that much of the work, but still an additional work to do for something that should be easy. And I would rather keep original Windows bar.

Comment: That's not how Windows works... You may need to grab the HWND via `winID` and set some attributes on it.  I'll look into this tonight...

Comment: I see you 've already got an accepted answer. But do check to see if my other answer makes sense (i.e. the  `MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint` flag).

Comment: To what I know, `MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint ` would disable resizing by dragging the edges of the widget, so you don't see resizing _arrows_ when you set this flag.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint` flag.

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint | Qt::Window | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
```